# How to shift a index in an array 3 positions to the right in javascript using only loops

Tags: javascript, loops

how can i shift the index's of an array 3 positions to the right , and looping the index's that reach the end of the array back to the begining of the array.
Using only loops and no functions.
Array=[5,10,30,60,50,30,20,2,5]

Thanks

Comment: You should try to solve this on your own first. If you don't try you won't learn anything from the solution. If you have tried then you should share what you tried here already.

Comment: Why "using only loops and no functions"?  How does that constraint help you?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds suspiciously like a homework question :)

```
var myArray = [5,10,30,60,50,30,20,2,5];

for(var x = 0; x < 3; x++){
    myArray.push(myArray.shift());
}
console.log(myArray);
```

If for some reason you can't use push/shift/pop/unshift

```
var myArray = [5,10,30,60,50,30,20,2,5];    
var newArray = [];
for(var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++){
    newArray[x] = myArray[(x + 3) % myArray.length];
}
console.log(newArray);
```

You can remove the first element and then continuously add it on the end.

Comment: Code-only answers without any accompanying explanation are not very helpful.